# Gdalinfo: error while loading shared libraries: libLerc.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: gdal, centos

While working from terminal in conda environment:

```sh
gdalinfo filename
```

Error is:

```sh
Gdalinfo: error while loading shared libraries:
  libLerc.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

GDAL is installed with conda.
There is no library like that.
On CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

How this problem could be fixed?

UPD: `gdalinfo --version` gives the same error.

GDAL version is `3.5.3`.

UPD2: I think the most useful answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75071381/where-can-i-find-liblerc-so-4-library-for-centos-7/75152579#75152579

Comment: I have the same error message. Can you find the library with `find / -name libLerc.so`? I get multiple results (we are using conda-store), so it is definitely installed on my system. It seems that gdal just cannot find the shared library.

Comment: I solved this by updating conda: `conda update -n base conda`

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu I can find both these Lerc related packages:

```sh
liblerc-dev - Limited Error Raster Compression library (Development files)
liblerc3 - Limited Error Raster Compression library
```

So maybe on RHEL subsystems you can try to install this package: https://rhel.pkgs.org/9/epel-x86_64/liblerc-3.1-0.2.gitb1de4cd.el9.x86_64.rpm.html

You will probably have to install dependencies also:

```sh
----> dependencies:
    libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.29)(64bit) is needed by liblerc-3.1-0.2.gitb1de4cd.el9.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) is needed by liblerc-3.1-0.2.gitb1de4cd.el9.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.29)(64bit) is needed by liblerc-3.1-0.2.gitb1de4cd.el9.x86_64
    rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1 is needed by liblerc-3.1-0.2.gitb1de4cd.el9.x86_64
```

Comment: It is for 9 Centos, what package should I install for CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)?
Here? https://rhel.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/